# Deviantart style image gallery CSS

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

I'm trying to make an image gallery using Django and python. I'm new to HTML and CSS and need to show the images in a grid. I want one image in a row to be the same height but different width like [Deviantart's](https://www.deviantart.com/). And the number of columns should be different like shown in the image below.

[image]

I am able to display the images in a gallery, like this.

[image]

but the images are not the same height and not in order. Is there any way to achieve a gallery like in the first image?

Thank you for your time!

**Update: This is the code I'm currently using.**

```css
.gallery-container {
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.gallery-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1e1f26;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.gallery-item img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-container">
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485550409059-9afb054cada4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=401&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493612276216-ee3925520721?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499854413229-6d1c92ff39ef?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=802&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489533119213-66a5cd877091?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=751&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500462918059-b1a0cb512f1d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496449903678-68ddcb189a24?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include your HTML and CSS with what you have tried?

Comment: @TannerDolby I updated the question, I should have included the code earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) you can accomplish this sort of "mosaic" image gallery layout. You just need to utilize [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) and [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row) on grid items to specify the specific columns and rows they should occupy. This should be a good starting point for you to customize the grid further and attempt achieving a pixel perfect "Deviantart" style image gallery.

```css
.gallery-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 7% 10%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, minmax(3rem, 8rem));
  gap: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.gallery-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1e1f26;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.two {
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.four {
  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.five {
  grid-column: 8 / 10;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.six {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}

.seven {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}

.eight {
  grid-column: 5;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}

.nine {
  grid-column: 6 / 10;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}

.gallery-item img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-container">
  <div class="gallery-item one">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485550409059-9afb054cada4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=401&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item two">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493612276216-ee3925520721?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item three">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499854413229-6d1c92ff39ef?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=802&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item four">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489533119213-66a5cd877091?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=751&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item five">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500462918059-b1a0cb512f1d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item six">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496449903678-68ddcb189a24?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item seven">
  <img src="https://bukk.it/ackbar.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item eight">
  <img src="https://media.contentapi.ea.com/content/dam/gin/images/2017/01/star-wars-battlefront-key-art.jpg.adapt.crop3x5.533p.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item nine">
  <img src="https://www.starwarsnewsnet.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/A-Family-at-War.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After you answered, I did some search and found what I was looking for https://css-tricks.com/adaptive-photo-layout-with-flexbox/ here. Your answer works too but I found this easier. Thank you!

Comment: @LuciferMorningstar Your welcome. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Is that work?

```css
.gallery-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:100%;
}

.gallery-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  background: #1e1f26;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.gallery-item img { 
  border-radius: 5px;  
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-container">
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485550409059-9afb054cada4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=401&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493612276216-ee3925520721?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499854413229-6d1c92ff39ef?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=802&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489533119213-66a5cd877091?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=751&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500462918059-b1a0cb512f1d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496449903678-68ddcb189a24?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```